# Can I add report viewer webpart to SharePoint 2013 foundation?

Tags: 2013

I created a application page with report viewer in it, but when I am trying to view it in sharepoint Foundation 2013, I get this error,

> Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.InvalidConfigFileTypeException: The type
>   'Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.Analytics.UI.ReportViewerMessages,
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' could not be found     at
>   Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.ConfigFilePropertyInterface`1.EnsurePropertyLoaded()

It looks like only way to make Report Viewer webpart in SharePoint is following this [guide](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwj77L6ThaLLAhXI0xQKHV7BDEEQFggpMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsvn.abisource.com%2Fabiword-testsuite%2Ftrunk%2Fimpexp%2Fdocx%2Fconfigure-rdlc-report-with-reportviewer.docx&usg=AFQjCNEhSAT6J27FHgwQ9DrJxNnYsTG1BA&sig2=zq9nT9xX6u9putiYbfknRQ&bvm=bv.115339255,d.d24).

Does anyone aware of any alternatives ?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but please look at [this](http://karukarthi.blogspot.ca/2014/02/sharepoint-2013configure-rdlc-report.html) blog post. Copied the related section below. Hope this helps!

1. Add the following tag inside system.web\httphandlers section



   type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, 
   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms,     Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
2. Add the following line in the system. Webserver\handlers

   verb="*" path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd" 
   type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, 
   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91" />
3. Comment out the following line in the system. Webserver\httphandlers (If Exists)

   path="Reserved.ReportViewerWebControl.axd"
   type="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.HttpHandler, 
   Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" />-->